# Angularjs conditional validation for as required field validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application using angularjs. I am trying to make validation for dropdown as below.

```
 <div ng-if="rankrequired">
 <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form3.rank.$invalid && form3.rank.$error.required && form3.rank.$dirty">*{{'Required' | translate}}</span>
  </div>
  <select id="rank" name="rank" ng-model="user.rank" ng-options="user.ID as user.Rank for user in rankList">
  <option value="" label="rank">{{ 'Rank' | translate }}</option>
  </select>
```

Whenever i make  `$scope.rankrequired = true;` above validation should work. 
Whenever i make  `$scope.rankrequired = false;` validation should not be there. I am trying to assign values  `$scope.rankrequired` true or false from the controller. However, above code does not work. May I know if there is a better way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no validation on select, its just for the message. Did you add the `required` attribute to select?

Comment: So what is the actual problem, the validation error or the select options? And is it intended to make the select outside the ng-if block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have `ng-required` defined on `select` for validation to get applied. Something like:

```
 <div ng-if="rankrequired">
 <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form3.rank.$invalid && form3.rank.$error.required && form3.rank.$dirty">*{{'Required' | translate}}</span>
  </div>
  <select id="rank" name="rank" ng-model="user.rank" ng-required="rankrequired"
    ng-options="user.ID as user.Rank for user in rankList">
  <option value="" label="rank">{{ 'Rank' | translate }}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: This is what i am looking. Working like charm.. Thanks a lot.